# Change the new file name in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way to change the default new file name from "new  #" to something else, or at least remove the space and/or replace it with an underline.

Comment: Check the solution #3 on [this page](http://sourceforge.net/apps/ideatorrent/notepad-plus/ideatorrent/idea/130/).

Comment: Looking for a way via a configuration.  Looks like only a code change can do this :-(

Answer (score 1):

See the solution I posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/620950/notepad-new-file-names). It requires that you install the Python Script plugin.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: I added the comment here on 2014-05-21, and subsequently had to update the original answer on 2015-07-13 due to a change with Notepad++. Had I duplicated the original answer here, I would have had to update both with the fix from 2015-07-13, which is typically the problem with duplicating information in multiple locations.

It's better that the answer I posted here reference the other answer than duplicating information in multiple locations that may run out of sync.

Comment: If the answer really is the same for both questions then this question should be flagged as a duplicate.