# Notepad++ new 1 file

Tags: notepad++

I have tried installing Notepad++ on my PC and I have stumbled upon the following behavior: when opening a new document a file called "new X" is created. My goal is to change that. I have tried [the following](https://superuser.com/questions/620950/notepad-new-file-names) with no result. What are the steps that are needed to be done to do what I have asked for?

Comment: What is the problem with "new X"? What do you want instead?

Comment: Do you want no document, or do you want a new document with a different name?

Answer (score 1):

I inspected Notepad++ 7.5.1 source code (for example in its GitHub repository see file `master/PowerEditor/src/Notepad_plus.cpp` at line **3430** and after) and it looks like Notepad++ is designed to always have at least one document open. In the code you can see that even if the last non-empty document is closed, it is immediately replaced by new document.

You can potentially modify this behavior by rewriting Notepad++ source code to your needs and created your custom build, but I doubt it is an easy task because the above behavior is there most likely for a reason, e.g. it might be needed to do much more checks in various text-editing methods if there was a possibility that no document is open.

So **tl;dr**: In Notepad++ you must always have at least one document open.

If you really want to find editor which allows closing all documents, try searching/asking for example at [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) site to obtain a recommendation for an alternative.